# Jackson module to handle abstract aggregate root and its subclasses in Spring Data REST

Tags: jackson, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have Spring Data REST based application with repository

```
public interface CriterionRepository extends JpaRepository<Criterion, Long> {
}
```

whereas `Criterion` is base class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Criterion extends AbstractEntity {}
```

and `NameCriterion` is its subclass

```
@Entity
public class NameCriterion extends Criterion {
    private final String name;
}
```

Spring Data REST exports the repository as REST resource and one can access it at http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/

Exported resource looks as follows:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "nameCriteria": [{
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/nameCriterion/1"
                    },
                    "nameCriterion": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/nameCriterion/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/criteria"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

When I try to follow self link, there is no mapping for http://localhost:8080/api/nameCriterion/1

I can follow http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/1 though and I get response without **name** field from `NameCriterion`

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/nameCriterion/1"
        },
        "nameCriterion": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/nameCriterion/1"
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption is it is a problem with Jackson mapper defined in REST exporter which is not tweaked correctly to handle abstract class `Criterion` used in `JpaRepository` as aggregate root.

What Jackson customization should I apply to make it working properly?

In other words, what Jackson module should I create?

Comment: If my answer helped you please don't forget to accept it! )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create a Jackson module. To use a single table for inherited entities we can use @RestResource annotation to mark them as the same resources:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "criteria")
public abstract class Criterion extends AbstractEntity {
}

@RestResource(rel = "criteria", path = "criteria")
@Entity
public class NameCriterion extends Criterion {

    private String name;
}

@RestResource(rel = "criteria", path = "criteria")
@Entity
public class TitleCriterion extends Criterion {

    private String title;
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "criteria", collectionResourceRel = "criteria", itemResourceRel = "criterion")
public interface CriterionRepository extends JpaRepository<Criterion, Long> {
}
```

So it becomes possible to obtain all the resources (NameCriterion and TitleCriterion) in one output:

```json
GET http://localhost:8080/api/criteria

{
  "_embedded": {
    "criteria": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/1"
          },
          "nameCriterion": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "title1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/2"
          },
          "titleCriterion": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

GET http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/1
{
  "name": "name1",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/1"
    },
    "nameCriterion": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/1"
    }
  }
}

GET http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/2
{
  "title": "title1",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/2"
    },
    "titleCriterion": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/criteria/2"
    }
  }
}
```

Working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example4).

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve my problem. I want to keep @Inheritance strategy on my base class

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin I've updated my answer. To pity the lost bounty... ))

Comment: Excellent. It works. I somehow forgot about @RestResource. Thanks! Just in time for bounty award - I had 24 hours to grant it ;)

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin Thanks for your bounty! ))

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin Hello! Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755908/repositoryrestresources-collectionresourcerel-attribute-not-being-obeyed/44761626#comment76510603_44761626)... ;)