# @RepositoryRestResource's collectionResourceRel attribute not being obeyed

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I have a MongoRepository of

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tools")
public interface ToolRepository extends MongoRepository<Tool, Long>
```

Tool can be one of 2 implementations:

```
public class Screwdriver extends Tool
public class Hammer extends Tool
```

Tool is mapped using @JsonTypeInfo

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = 
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = 
As.PROPERTY, property = "_class")
public abstract class Tool
```

When I do `toolRepository.findAll()` this returns a JSON response of :

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "screwdrivers" : [ {
      "name" : "Screwdriver",
      ...
    } ],
    "hammers" : [ {
      "name" : "Hammer",
      ...
      }
 }
```

Expected response should be :

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "tools" : [ {
      "name" : "Screwdriver",
      ...
      },
      {
      "name" : "Hammer",
      ...
      }
 }
```

The `collectionResourceRel` is not being obeyed for classes with Json mapping data in.

Investigating further; `PersistentEntitiesResourceMapping.getMetadataFor()` (within Spring) is saying make sure that if there's no entry for these subclasses of tool inside the ResourceMetadata cache then use a `TypeBasedCollectionResourceMapping` which results in each class having its own entry in the json response.

**Is there a way of telling Spring data rest that a specific subclass should be bound to a specific repository, in this case is there a way of telling Spring data rest that Screwdriver is part of the `ToolRepository` and therefore should use the `collectionResourceRel` of this repository?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set these annotations:

```java
@RestResource(rel = "tools", path = "tools")
public abstract class Tool {...}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "tools", collectionResourceRel = "tools", itemResourceRel = "tool")
public interface ToolRepository extends MongoRepository<Tool, Long> {...}
```

See working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example4). It's not about Mongo but I'm sure it will be useful...

Comment: Thanks a lot - the `@RestResource` seems to do the trick. Somewhat annoying to have to add the annotation to all my subclasses (I have a few more than the above) but it sorts my problem out. Thank you again

Comment: Ignore the above caveat - adding the annotation to the hypothetical `Tool` class avoids my problem of having to add it to all the subclasses so perfect answer.

Comment: @alex.p Confirm the same behavior in my code. Thanks Alex! I will correct my answer...